# PowerShell Remoting: No credentials are available in the security package

Tags: powershell, windows

I'm trying to use the following script:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxxx" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("domain\Administrator", $password)
$session = New-PSSession 192.168.xxx.xxx -Credential $cred
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { New-Cluster -Name "ClusterTest" -Node HOSTNAME }
```

To remotely create a cluster (it's for testing purposes) on a Windows Server 2012 VM. I'm getting the following error:

```
An error occurred while performing the operation.
    An error occurred while creating the cluster 'ClusterTest'.
    An error occurred creating cluster 'ClusterTest'.
    No credentials are available in the security package
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Cluster], ClusterCmdletException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : New-Cluster,Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.NewClusterCommand
```

All of my other remote commands (installing/making changes to DNS, DHCP, NPAS, GP, etc) work without an issue. Why is this one any different? The only difference is in the -ScriptBlock tag. Help!

Comment: Have tried `Administrator@domain` instead of `domain\Administrator`?

Comment: @HopelessN00b Yeah, I just tried it. No such luck.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas.  All the Google results on that error seemed entirely unrelated.  Unless... if you manually provide `New-Cluster` with credentials, does it fail with the same error?

Comment: How would I go about doing that? @HopelessN00b

Comment: @TheSciz The Invoke-Command cmdlet has a -Authentication parameter that allows different authentication methods to be used. See Get-Help Invoke-Command -Full and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.management.automation.runspaces.authenticationmechanism(v=vs.85).aspx for more info.